# Nested looping in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, automated-tests, pytest

As we all now, for iterating a simple test we can go with the following script

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("b", ["b1", "b2", "b3"])
def test_3(b):
    pass
```

the output would be

```
test_1.py::test_3[b1] PASSED
test_1.py::test_3[b2] PASSED
test_1.py::test_3[b3] PASSED
```

Then if I want to loop through multiple tests as one scenario, I do class parameterization:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], scope="class")
class TestAB:

    def test_1(self, a):
        pass

    def test_2(self, a):
        pass

    def test_3(self, a):
        pass
```

we get

```
test_1.py::TestAB::test_1[a1] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_2[a1] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[a1] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_1[a2] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_2[a2] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[a2] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_1[a3] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_2[a3] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[a3] PASSED
```

These 2 scripts produce expected output

### Question

What do I write in order to combine these two and to loop a test within a class loop, so I get this output

```
test_1.py::TestAB::test_1[a1] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_2[a1] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b1-a1] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b2-a1] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b3-a1] PASSED

test_1.py::TestAB::test_1[a2] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_2[a2] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b1-a2] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b2-a2] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b3-a2] PASSED

test_1.py::TestAB::test_1[a3] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_2[a3] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b1-a3] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b2-a3] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b3-a3] PASSED
```

#### What I tried and didn't work

1. Logically, I wrote

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a", ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], scope="class")
class TestAB:

    def test_1(self, a):
        pass

    def test_2(self, a):
        pass

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("b", ["b1", "b2", "b3"])
    def test_3(self, a, b):
        pass
```

But that produced

```
test_1.py::TestAB::test_1[a1] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_2[a1] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b1-a1] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_1[a2] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_2[a2] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b1-a2] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_1[a3] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_2[a3] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b1-a3] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b2-a1] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b2-a2] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b2-a3] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b3-a1] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b3-a2] PASSED
test_1.py::TestAB::test_3[b3-a3] PASSED
```

2. I also used [pytest-order](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/) and [pytest-ordering](https://github.com/ftobia/pytest-ordering) to define the order. But they even broke the initial expected order of class iteration itself

Comment: So you are happy with the current output except for its ordering?

Comment: why does the order of the tests matter? shouldn't they be independent of one another

Comment: @oli yes, but since it's a test scenario, it has `0` value without keeping the order

Comment: @gold_cy if you use `pytest` for unit testing - yes, maybe having independent tests is a plus. What I'm doing is scenario based test, which may require sending multiple API requests and using data of first response in the second request etc example from pytest docs here - https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#a-quick-port-of-testscenarios

Comment: `pytest` is meant for unit testing for the most part. technically your tests should not be hitting actual API endpoints as that goes against the unit test concept.

Comment: @gold_cy I disagree. Pytest's webpage describes it as follows `The pytest framework makes it easy to write small tests, yet scales to support complex functional testing for applications and libraries.` some webpages like www.tutorialspoint.com and www.guru99.com even suggest it's `mainly used to write API test cases`. A lot of APIs are workflow based and thus testing one API requires sending multiple requests as prerequisite, which is what I'm trying to do. Though, I must admit it's not very convenient to write tests as scenarios with pytest

Comment: `pytest-order`/`pytest-ordering` do not support this (as you found), as there is no way to define the wanted order using order markers. I could think about adding this to pytest-order, but I struggle to even think about how to express the wanted order. Frankly I would have expected the default order to be as you expect instead of how it is currently - you may bring up this in [pytest discussions](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/discussions), maybe someone has an explanation or a way to get the expected output.